# python opencv cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cn)

Tags: python, opencv

Someone may explain this code to me.

```
for cn in range(0,3):
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cn)
    if cam.isOpened():
        break
```

I know how it works with cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0), cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1) and cv2.VideoCapture("file name.mp4"), but I've never seen initializing a camera in this form.

4 times initializing?

best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code tries to open the device `0`, `1` or `2` in that order. It stops on the first success.